# Modal Popup Jquery Validation with MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am loading a Modal popup form using PartialView

The code

```
 $("#modalContainer").load('@Url.Action("NewRefill","Car",new {car=@Model.Id})');

                        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#modalContainer form"));

                        $("#addNewEntryModal").modal('show');
```

in my Controller I have

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult NewRefill(Car car,int car)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {


            }
            return Json(new { Success = false });

        }
```

This is a Modal popup. Every time You hit submit, it automatically forwards you to a new page. What I would like it to do would be to Keep the Modal open and show the Errors that happen. I have tried binding to the Submit event and stopping it to no avail. The validations do work since I see the Red borders but I get forwarded and see the Success=false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not parsing the jQuery unobtrusive validations at the right place. You should do that once you load the partial, inside the success callback:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("NewRefill", "Car", new {car = @Model.Id})';
$('#modalContainer').load(url, function() {
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#modalContainer form"));
    $("#addNewEntryModal").modal('show');
});
```

Also if inside this partial you are using an `Ajax.BeginForm` helper to generate the form make sure that you have included the `jQuery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script to your page for this to work. And if it is a normal `Html.BeginForm` you should AJAXify it if you want it to be submitted with an AJAX request instead of a normal request:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("NewRefill", "Car", new {car = @Model.Id})';
$('#modalContainer').load(url, function() {
    var form = $("#modalContainer form");
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse();
    $("#addNewEntryModal").modal('show');
    form.submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(result) {
                ...
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#' + popupID));
```